# Queries overwriting with missing fields in the Apollo cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a situation where I sometimes want to query a list of many objects with a few fields, and sometimes only one object with many fields. As an example, consider these two queries:

- A query with a many objects and few fields:

  ```
  query {
    object(many=true) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
  ```
- A query with a single object and many fields:

  ```
  query {
    object(many=false) {
      id
      ... (many other fields)
    }
  }
  ```

I don't want to ask for more fields than necessary in the first query, because this will result in requests with a lot of data (otherwise I could make the fields identical, e.g. using a `fragment`, solving my issue).

The issue is: The data stored in the cache is normalised and stored according to the `__typename` and `id`. This means queries, or atoms of queries, will overwrite each other if these are the same. Therefore, if the second query happens last, the item in the database has no `name` field, required by components associated with the first query.

The simplest solution is just to ask for `name` in the second query as well. The problem is that this seems fragile and error prone; for example one might create a third query and forget to ask for `name` there.

Another option is to make these have different `__typename`'s, i.e. differentiate them on the backend. But this seems sort of artificial; the queries are in reality dealing with the same kind of object.

Is there a canonical way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone ending up here: turns out that in the current version at least (@apollo/client 3.3.6) the data is merged, so this is not an issue.